# Как распечатать документ

Tags: c#, печать

Пытаюсь печатать документ, но печатает пустой документ, подскажите, где я ошибся:

```
var printDocument = new PrintDocument();
var printDialog = new PrintDialog();
printDialog.ShowHelp = true;
printDialog.AllowSomePages = true;
printDialog.Document = printDocument;
printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = @"C:\2132.docx";
printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;

if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    printDocument.Print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Так вы пока ничего не выводите на печать, поэтому документ и пустой.

Нужно обработать событие `PrintPage` и там указать, что вы будете печатать:

```
printDocument.PrintPage +=
                new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    //тут печатаете, что хотите
    Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    float xPos = 100;
    float yPos = 100;

    e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello, world", myFont, Brushes.Black,
          xPos, yPos, new StringFormat());

    // если будет еще страница, то true
    e.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog())
{
pd.ShowDialog();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\Docs\file.doc");
info.Verb = "PrintTo";
info.Arguments = pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process.Start(info);
}
```